# Get X number of random dates in a order time range?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to create a function which outputs X number of dates where the dates are in order of time (so date1 < date2 < date3 etc). I need this a sample input data.

I have come up with this function so far, but does it matter the array keys are not in order after the uasort???

```
   function getRandomDateTime($startDate, $endDate, $num) {
    $dateTmp = '';
    $dateArr = [];
    $rndDat = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $randomTime = mt_rand(strtotime($startDate), strtotime($endDate));
        $rndDate = date('Y-m-d', $randomTime);
        $dateArr[] .= $rndDate;


    }
    return $dateArr;

}
$test = getRandomDateTime('2015-06-03', '2017-05-12', 10);
print_r($test);

function sortByTime($a, $b){
  $a = strtotime($a);
  $b = strtotime($b);
  return $a - $b;
}
uasort($test, 'sortByTime');

print_r($test);
```

Comment: `$dateArr[] .= $rndDate;` ~ should that not be `$dateArr[] = $rndDate;` without the `.`?

Comment: Just use `usort()`. `uasort()` maintains the index association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something then can you not simply use `sort` within the function to return a sorted array?

```
function getRandomDateTime( $start, $end, $num ) {
    $arr=array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < $num; $i++ ) {
        $arr[]=date('Y-m-d', mt_rand( strtotime( $start ), strtotime( $end ) ) );
    }
    sort( $arr, SORT_REGULAR );
    return $arr;
}

$test = getRandomDateTime('2013-06-03', '2018-02-01', 10 );
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $test,true ) );
```

Will produce output similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-30
    [1] => 2014-06-25
    [2] => 2014-09-15
    [3] => 2014-11-19
    [4] => 2015-03-24
    [5] => 2015-05-30
    [6] => 2015-08-15
    [7] => 2016-02-12
    [8] => 2017-02-10
    [9] => 2018-01-19
)
```

Comment: hi I never used a simple sort with sort_regular before didn't cross my mind. But should I use sortdate, then?